# ActionListener not responding [example]

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I have ActionListener class implemented as parameter and isn't responding.

I'm using MVC pattern and calling controllers within other controllers.
I have created simplified version of my program (which still isn't working).

I have one frame with one button which when pressed prints in console.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton button = new JButton("Print");

    public MainFrame() {
        setSize(200, 100);

        this.add(button);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(MainFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void validateButton(ActionListener e) {
        this.button.addActionListener(e);
    }
}
```

Here is the action

```
public class ValidateAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }

}
```

I call this action inside of EditController

```
public class EditController {

    private MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();

    public EditController(MainFrame mf) {
        this.mf = mf;

        this.mf.validateButton(new ValidateAction());
    }

}
```

I call this EditController inside of MenuController

```
public class MenuController {

    public MenuController(MainFrame mf) {

        this.makeEditController(mf);
    }

    public void makeEditController(MainFrame mf) {
        new EditController(mf);
    }

}
```

And I call MenuController inside of main Controller

```
public class Controller {

    public Controller(MainFrame mf) {

        this.makeMenuController(mf);
    }

    public void makeMenuController(MainFrame mf) {
        new MenuController(mf);
    }

}
```

Finally I call everything in main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        new Controller(mf);
    }

}
```

And it's not working...

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: There is no error, it just does nothing.

Comment: Eliminate what's working properly, and post a [MCVE].  (Doing so is also a good debugging technique ). Also in `EditController` why `private MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();` ? It should be `private MainFrame mf;`

Comment: It works when I call it inside of MenuController.

Comment: FIXED: Apparently I just had to delete "this.mf = mf;" from EditController.
I'm not sure why that was problem.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion of @c0der to post an MCVE. For starters, By making everything but the `Main` default access, and including all the other classes below it in the same code block, it would only take a single copy/ paste to compile and run the class. You should also make more effort to remove unnecessary code and classes.

Comment: You are creating `MainFrame` twice, but i think you removed the wrong one. In `EditController` change `private MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();`  to `private MainFrame mf;`

Comment: Yes, that worked as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `MainFrame` twice. See comment:

```
class EditController {

    private MainFrame mf; //= new MainFrame();

    public EditController(MainFrame mf) {
        this.mf = mf;
        this.mf.validateButton(new ValidateAction());
    }
}
```